# Добавление элементов из списка в словарь

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dict

Столкнулся с такой проблемой: у меня есть список, в котором есть n-ное количество элементов (текст); мне нужно эти элементы поочередно занести в словарь с одинаковым ключом, чтобы в конце у меня выходил словарь с одинаковым ключом для элементов, но с разными значениями.

Список который у меня есть.

```
list = ["text1","text2"?,"text3","text4","text5","text6"]
```

Словарь который мне нужно получить на выходе.

```
dict = {'name':'text1','name':'text2','name':'text3','name':'text4','name':'text5','name':'text6'}
```

Большое спасибо за ответ!

Comment: У словаря не может быть несколько одинаковых ключей

Comment: Вы хотите странного, одному ключу может соответствовать только одно значение.  Можете, разумеется, записать в словарь список как значение: `dict["names"] = list` -> `dict = {'names': ['text1', 'text2', 'text3', 'text4', 'text5', 'text6']}`

Comment: Невозможно получить такой словарь. Если вы напечатаете переменную с вашим словарём, то получите только последнюю пару ключ:значение `{'name': 'text6'}`

Answer (score 4):

python не позволяет получить такой словарь.
Если попробовать вывести ваш словарь, то мы получим `{'name': 'text6'}`
Т. к. одному ключу может соответствовать только одно значение.

Но можно записать в словарь список как значение

```
from collections import defaultdict

responses = defaultdict(list)
list1 = ["text1", "text2", "text3", "text4", "text5", "text6"]
responses['name'].append(list1)
```

Эту задачу можно решить с помощью классов

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def __repr__(self):
        return repr(self.name)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


list1 = ["text1", "text2", "text3", "text4", "text5", "text6"]
dict1 = dict()
for i in list1:
    dict1[A('name')] = i
```

Если мы выведем на экран dict1, то получим

```
{'name': 'text1', 'name': 'text2', 'name': 'text3', 'name': 'text4', 'name': 'text5', 'name': 'text6'}
```

Comment: Красивый трюк. А если в `__repr__` сделать совсем правильно и возвращать `return repr(self.name)`, то будет совсем как автор вопроса хотел - ещё и с кавычками ))

Comment: не знал о таком, спасибо)

Comment: Оч круто. Тоже не знал. Остался один вопрос. Вопрос практического применения данной конструкции (Ну кроме ответа автору)

Comment: А я смогу потом  в дальнейшем работать с таким словарем как и с  обычным словарем? Не будет никаких проблем?

Comment: @Nazar Нет, как с обычным - вряд ли, увы )